# Can you change displayed exposure when bracketing with D7500

Tags: nikon, exposure, bracketing, nikon-d7500

I am using bracketing on both a D850 and D7500, and the issue I want to "fix" is the same for both cameras (and probably across all Nikon (D)SLRs)

When setting up a set of bracketing, you choose the number of shots around a base exposure.  EG I could choose 3F and the bracketing program would be to take shots that are (using 1 EV differences) -1, 0, +1 EV difference from the base exposure.

Typically I am setting up a manual base exposure 1/250, F16, and 5F, with a 1EV separation.  This gives me a program of:

```
1/1000 F/16 
1/500  F/16
1/250  F/16 <= Base exposure
1/125  F/16
1/60   F/16
```

Now, one of the bracketing options is to set the bracketing order as being either:

1. MTR > under > over
2. under > MTR > over

With option #1, the cameras take the shots in this order:

```
1 1/250  F/16 <= Base exposure
2 1/1000 F/16 
3 1/500  F/16
4 1/125  F/16
5 1/60   F/16
```

While with #2, the order is indeed

```
1 1/1000 F/16 
2 1/500  F/16
3 1/250  F/16 <= Base exposure
4 1/125  F/16
5 1/60   F/16
```

I prefer #2 so I can see a nice transition across all the shots in the bracket.

The problem I have is that the LCD on top of the camera shows the exposure of the first image in the bracketing series.

This is ok for #1, as I directly see my manual exposure.

But for #2 it shows me "1/1000 F/16".  Which at times confuses me as I am second guessing what I actually set the exposure to be, and as I am thinking of a series of shots surrounding a base exposure.  The confusion increases when after looking at my histograms I want to modify my base exposure, but changing a command dial updates the display with the exposure of that first image, and not of my base exposure. (I have at times ended up setting the order to MTR > under > over, changing the exposure, and then returning the order to under > MTR > over.  Which is a really clumsy way to do things)

My question is, with the bracketing order set to  "under > MTR > over" is there any way to set the camera's display to show the base exposure, and not the exposure of the first image it will take?

Comment: *the display of the camera shows the exposure of the first image in the bracketing series* How / where / when do you see that information?

Comment: @MrUpsidown In the LCD on the top of the camera to start with

Comment: When you review the images on the camera's rear LCD with the exposure information also displayed, what does it show? The same exposure for all of the images or the actual exposure for each image?

Comment: How are you setting exposure? Manual, Aperture Priority, Shutter priority, or something else?

Comment: I could find no help about that in the user manual and indeed I can see the same behavior on my D750. Quite weird.

Comment: @MichaelC I'm setting the exposure manually.  And I do see the correct progression of exposures through the bracketing.  The functioning aspect of the bracketing is correct, it's only the exposure numerical display on the LCD that is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to make the camera do what you want... about the best you can do is to turn off exposure preview so you don't see the changes in liveview. But that's pretty useless if you are wanting to use the histogram; and it won't affect the exposure settings that are displayed/changed (e.g. SS).

Rather than changing the bracketing sequence it's probably easier/quicker to just cancel bracketing; or switch the camera to manual exposure. I have the movie record button, next to the shutter button on my D850, set to "mode;" so I just tap that button and turn the rear dial to get back to manual mode. I can do that w/o moving my hands, nor looking up from the viewfinder (I also have the "hold button" requirement disabled).

Comment: I'm not talking about LiveView, I'm talking about the exposure settings displayed in the LCD.  Also the with option #1 the time sequence will always have the base exposure as the first image. So sorting on time won't help.

Comment: @PeterM, OK, I edited my response now that I understand better (I had just deleted/hidden it).

Comment: Hmm is there any way to program a button to turn bracketing on/off?  That would probably be the best result.  But it still sucks as having to remember to complete steps in order is apt to cause issues when you are fixated on the subject.

Comment: @PeterM No, only the BKT button works with bracketing; and it doesn't directly turn it off. But I can only think of one situation where the middle "proper" exposure is most important and would need changed directly. Most of the time what you would really want to do is extend the bracket sequence.

Comment: My normal use case is shooting the moon around dawn when it is just about to set.  I want a fixed, known best exposure for the moon (based on [Looney 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looney_11_rule) ) and then range up and down around that in order to get decent exposures of the surrounding landscape (well, mainly down).  I try to set the camera up the night before as I don't want to be fiddling with things in the dark and 10F to 20F temperatures. But sometimes you have to do what you have to do.